# Need to check if we can add different browsers in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I need to check in Jmeter whether we can add different browsers to test. We have that option in loadrunner in runtimesettings to test with different browsers.

Thanks
Roshan

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about [Browser Emulation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/2021-2021_R1/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/c_browser_emulation_overview.htm) - it's just sending the relevant [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) string

In JMeter you can achieve the same using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

[image]

The list of possible `User-Agent` header values can be found at i.e. http://useragentstring.com website

Comment: thx i got it what i need